# Need code to delete rows based on value (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, macos

What I'm trying to do is get this code to delete rows based on the date in Column B. If the date in column B falls within the last 3 days, it should get deleted. The code seems to delete 1 or 2 rows, but not all rows with 'bad' dates.

I have tried setting the formatting of all columns to General. The formatting is fine so that's not the issue. I converted the dates to numbers so I could get the last 3 days and not run into error. It should be known that this data is starting as a .csv file and is being saved as an excel file earlier in the code.

```
Dim myrow As Long
Dim mydate As Long

mydate = Int(CDbl(Now()))
mydate = mydate - 3

Columns("B:B").NumberFormat = "0"

Application.CutCopyMode = False

MsgBox "Last row with data:" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row

For myrow = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row Step 1

        If Range("B" & myrow).value = mydate + 1 Or Range("B" & myrow).value = mydate + 2 Or Range("B" & myrow).value = mydate + 3 Then
        Range("B" & myrow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If

Next myrow
```

I expect this code to delete all rows which contain any of the last 3 days in Column B. Column B is a set of dates formatted as "43588" "43599" etc. However, it is only deleting 1 or 2 rows when the code runs. I have a message box which tells the last row with data, and it is showing correct values, meaning "Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row" works fine.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Is there Blank cells into your column B ?

Comment: No blank cells in B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When deleting rows in a loop, you must iterate through the rows in reverse order (bottom-to-top). Otherwise, when you delete a row, the rows below it are renumbered and might be skipped.

```
For myrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row to 1 Step -1
```